# org-meta-up, on normal text

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I've found the move-text package, which does what I want; moving lines up and down with M-UP.

This however, is the same keybinding as org-meta-up, which moves org-headings up and down.

I don't want to lose org-meta-up and I actually want both functions.

1. When I M-UP on normal text, I want the text to move up
2. When I M-UP on org-headings, I want the headings to move up

Any pointers as to how I can achieve that?;)

Comment: `org-metaup` (note the spelling) is already context-dependent, so you *could* expand it with an additional context dependency. In fact, it could be made configurable, so that people who want to do something other than what the move-text package does could do their own thing. That might be worth submitting for inclusion to Org mode.

Comment: Actually, it's already available: `C-h v org-metaup-hook`.